# CLion plugin with python packages

Tags: bazel

I want to implement a python project built with bazel in CLion.
But I can't get auto-completion and import resolving running, means I can't easily "Go to" imported files.

I am using Python 2018.3.4 and the Bazel plugin v2019.04.15. I build with bazel version 0.25.0.

I also checked out the fix in the drake repository:
https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/tree/master/tools/clion
But CLion still doesn't resolve the imports.

Does anybody have a solution for CLion or run a different IDE where python packages are nicely integrated?